# sendKeys is not a function Appium javascript Android

Tags: javascript, android, appium, sendkeys

I need to send a text into a textfield with hint text.

The code i tried

```
var button = $("#button");
button.click();
var input = $("#input");
input.sendKeys("hello");
```

However it return me sendKeys is not a function. May i know is there any solutions for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your sendKeys function supposed to be coming from?  What plugin/documentation are you using?

Comment: @Deadron i'm using appium as to automate the mobile test in android

Comment: What I am trying to ask you is what told you to use the sendKeys function?  If you look at http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/actions/send-keys/ you will see the sendKeys only exists on a MobileElement object. It looks like you might be using webdriver.io which does not have a sendKeys function.

Comment: @Deadron   I had tried addValue and setValue, both also said it is not a function?

Answer (score 1):

As per appium [official documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/actions/send-keys/) for Javascript, you can use `addValue` function in webdriver.io and `type` in webdriver. Please have a look on below code snippet.

```
// webdriver.io example
$("~SomeAccessibilityId").addValue("Enter");

// wd example
let element = await driver.elementByAccessibilityId("SomeAccessibilityID");
await element.type("Hello world!")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
input.click();
driver.adbSendText("Type Something")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30064729)